# Exercise II.20 in Frohlich and Taylor Alg. Num Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathfrak{o}$ be a Dedekind domain with field of fractions $K$ and let $F=K(X)$. Extend the definition of the content ideal $\mathfrak{a}_f$ to rational functions $f$ by $$\mathfrak{a}_{g/h} = \mathfrak{a}_g \cdot \mathfrak{a}_h^{-1}$$ if $g, h \in K[X], h \neq 0,$ and $\mathfrak{a}_0=0$. I can prove that this definition of a content ideal extended to rational functions in $F$ is well-defined. (Previously, the content ideal was only defined for $f \in K[X]$ as the $\mathfrak{o}$-submodule of $K$ generated by the coefficients of $f$.) However, I have difficulty showing the following:

If $\mathfrak{b}$ is a fractional ideal of $\mathfrak{o},$ define
$$ \bar{\mathfrak{b}} = \{ f \in F \;|\; \mathfrak{a}_f \subset \mathfrak{b} \}$$

**Prove that $\bar{\mathfrak{o}}$ is a PID with field of fractions $F$**. I have difficulty showing the statement in bold. I understand that $\bar{\mathfrak{o}}$ is equal to $\{ f=g/h \in F \;|\; \mathfrak{a}_f=\mathfrak{a}_{g/h}=\mathfrak{a}_f \cdot \mathfrak{a}_g^{-1} \subset \mathfrak{o} \}$, but I don't have an intuition regarding how I can show it is a PID. Would you be able to give a hint?

Comment: The “field of fractions” part is easy because $\mathfrak{o}[X]$ is contained in $\overline{\mathfrak{o}}$. For the PID – I’m not sure if this works or if something more is needed – I’d start with the following heuristic: “when given an ideal which should be principal, the generator should be an element which is somehow the least divisible”. So given an ideal of $\overline{\mathfrak{o}}$, what could be a candidate for “the least divisible element”?

Comment: For ideals $\bar{\mathfrak{b}}$ of $\bar{\mathfrak{o}}$, the text of the exercise suggests looking at $\bar{\mathfrak{b}}\cap K$ $=$ $\bar{\mathfrak{b}}\cap\mathfrak{o}$. If the latter equals $(a_0,\cdots,a_n)$, consider the element $f$ $=$ $\sum_{\,0\leq i\leq n}a_iX^i$ of $F$.